# Use argdo with search pattern to delete line while suppressing errors and requiring confirmation in Vim

Tags: vim

I use gVim 7.3.46 on Win 7.

It is pretty straightforward to use `argdo` to search `args` files for a pattern and replace it while suppressing errors and requiring confirmation.

```
:argdo %s/pattern/replace/gec | update
```

However, I would like to delete entire lines that contain the pattern. I use the following.

```
:argdo %/pattern/d | update
```

But I can't suppress errors or require confirmation. Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

(Also, is there a way to set "more" off? Thanks!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can suppress some errors by preceding the command with `:silent`. To delete lines containing a pattern, the command is `:g/pattern/d`. So the following should do what you want.

```
:silent argdo g/pattern/d | update
```

See

```
:help :silent
:help :g
```

To turn "more" off,

```
:set nomore
```

Also see

```
:help 'more'
:help more-prompt
:help messages
```

How to deal with confirmations depends on what needs to be confirmed. Putting a `!` after a command often means, "Do it anyway."

Comment: Thanks! Is there I way that I could get the `s///gec` functionality? Maybe something like `argdo %s/pattern/^$//gec`? But I think this just deletes the contents on the line, not the whole line.

Comment: To get `s///gec` to delete an entire line, use this: `%s/.*pattern.*\n//ec`. The `\n` will match the end-of-line marker even for a DOS file. The `g` isn't necessary if you're deleting the entire line.

Comment: this is so awesome thank you! `:set nomore`, `:arga **/*` and `:argdo execute 'normal gg=G' | w` fixes all the ugly indenting on a project I'm working on.